# java code to install software without permission

Tags: java

I want to install xml-twig-tools using java code.
part of my java code is:

```
 Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo apt-get install xml-twig-tools");
  p.waitFor();
```

This code is working in localhost but not on server.
Can anyone help me to get this worked?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you run the command manually on the server does it prompt you for a password ?

Comment: haven't checked manually on server

Comment: But cant we install without permission

Comment: on Linux if you don't have the rights, nope.

Comment: so ids there any way to get permissions through java

Comment: Not really, a admin user on the server needs to give you the rights. If your problem is that it prompts you for a password then this should help http://askubuntu.com/questions/470383/how-to-avoid-prompt-password-for-sudo

Comment: no its not prompting for password i checked but its giving error regarding some path locked

Comment: I guess that's your problem